# Solidity: ParserError: Expected primary expression

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I coded this

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import  "/contracts/HAHA.sol";

interface ERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}
```

collegated to this being HAHA.sol

```
contract Contract {
    function main() {
        
        memory[0x40:0x60] = 0x80;
```

But gives this error

```
ParserError: Expected primary expression.
 --> contracts/HAHA.sol:4:9:
  |
4 |         memory[0x40:0x60] = 0x80;
  |         ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi, what did you try to do here? Solidity does not allow direct memory manipulation through array-style indexing. If you really need to do this, you can use assembly (for solidity). Also, memory is a keyword in solidity, so you can't use it as the name of a an array.